# Unable to use collectAsMap() in scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
 val titleMap = movies.map(line => line.split("\\|")).take(2)

//converting movie-id and movie name as map(key-pair)

val title1 = titleMap.map(array=>(array(0).toInt,array(1)))
```

---

```
val titles = movies.map(line => line.split("\\|").take(2)).map(array
=> (array(0).toInt,
    array(1))).collectAsMap()
```

Whats wrong here with "title1",I am unable to apply collectAsMap function here,same thing I can apply in case of "titles"

Comment: I notice that in the 1st case your `take(2)` is outside of the `map()` call.  In the 2nd case it is inside the first `map()` call.

Comment: sorry for that typo, @jwvh,it worked now

Answer (score 1):

The type of `title1` is not an `RDD`, so it doesn't have the method `collectAsMap()`.

The type of `titles` is an `RDD` so it does have the method `collectAsMap()`.

Advise reading up on types https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system